# Suppressing 'Excel has stopped working' dialogue box

Tags: windows, excel, ms-office, application-restart, windows-error-reporting

How to suppress / automate a response to the 'Microsoft Excel has stopped working' dialogue box shown below?  I already have disabled autosave for the WB in question.  I'd like to bypass the dialogue box and immediately initiate the auto-restart.  If the box hangs around for long enough (more than an hour?) i think it does actually restart, but I'm for a way to do this immediately.

[image: Excel has stopped working]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that by design, as you can lose precious data when a program gets force-shutdown. Defaulting to doing this as soon as windows notices the program failing is not possible, but if it would help you can disable the pop-up using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) guide.